# how can I verify if the entered invoice number already exist is my sql table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, t-sql

I have a function named `InvoiceNumber_OnChange()` where I am trying to implement some code that allow me to verify if the entered invoice number already exist is my sql table. Here is what I have so far.

```
function InvoiceNumber_OnChange()
{ 
  var invoice = $("#InvoiceNumber").val();
  var Sql1 = null;

  if (invoice != "")
  {
      Sql1 = "SELECT [DocumentNumber] FROM [DYNAMICS].[dbo].[AP_Invoice_Table] 
      WHERE DocumentNumber = '" + invoice +"'";

      if (Sql1) 
      {
        CSClient.alert("Invoice number already exist, please check your entry!")
        return false;
      }
      else return true;
     }

}
```

That doesn't work because this is not the proper form to get the sql query value(I don't know how to do it). I would like that query returns me a true or false or something if the invoice # is found, so that will allow me to enter the if statement depending on the value stored on SQL1 variable.

Could someone please help me writing the missing code?

Comment: I'd be extraordinarily careful here. As it stands, the #InvoiceNumber element is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, big time. Read up and protect yourself.

Comment: this form will be working in an intranet, no one will have access unless has been registered on the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [DYNAMICS].[dbo].[AP_Invoice_Table] 
      WHERE DocumentNumber = '" + invoice +"'"`.

If it returns > 0 then the value already exists.

Comment: I did this Sql1 = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [DYNAMICS].[dbo].[AP_Invoice_Table] WHERE DocumentNumber = '" + invoice +"'"; but that doesn't returned me a numeric value, it returned me the whole sql statement, probably I am doing something wrong or missed an step

Comment: cojimarmiami, you need to actually execute your query.   You would be much better off using PHP, .NET, etc.  As pointed out, you're already exposing yourself to SQL injection.  Using Javascript introduces more security issues.

Comment: that is exactly what I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, in your select statement, it looks like you are opening yourself to a sql injection attack vector.